# Creating columns with numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have some elements stored in `numpy.array[]`. I wish to store them in a ".txt" file. The case is it needs to fit a certain standard, which means each element needs to be stored x lines into the file.

Example:

`numpy.array[0]` needs to start in line 1, col 26.

`numpy.array[1]` needs to start in line 1, col 34.

I use `numpy.savetxt()` to save the arrays to file.

Later I will implement this in a loop to create a lagre ".txt" file with coordinates.

Edit: This good example was provided below, it does point out my struggle:

```
 In [117]: np.savetxt('test.txt',A.T,'%20d %10d')
 In [118]: cat test.txt
                   0          6
                   1          7
                   2          8
                   3          9
                   4         10
                   5         11
```

The fmt option '%20d %10d' gives you spacing which depend on the last integer. What I need is an option which lets me set the spacing from the left side regardless of other integers.

Template is need to fit integers into:
XXXXXXXX.XXX YYYYYYY.YYY ZZZZ.ZZZ

---

Final Edit:

I solved it by creating a test which checks how many spaces the last float used. I was then able to predict the number of spaces the next float needed to fit the template.

Comment: Would not say that post answers my question @k4ppa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you played with the `fmt` of `np.savetxt`?

Let me illustrate with a concrete example (the sort that you should have given us)

Make a 2 row array:

```
In [111]: A=np.arange((12)).reshape(2,6)
In [112]: A
Out[112]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Save it, and get 2 rows, 6 columns

```
In [113]: np.savetxt('test.txt',A,'%d')
In [114]: cat test.txt
0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10 11
```

save its transpose, and get 6 rows, 2 columns

```
In [115]: np.savetxt('test.txt',A.T,'%d')
In [116]: cat test.txt
0 6
1 7
2 8
3 9
4 10
5 11
```

Put more detail into `fmt` to space out the columns

```
In [117]: np.savetxt('test.txt',A.T,'%20d %10d')
In [118]: cat test.txt
                   0          6
                   1          7
                   2          8
                   3          9
                   4         10
                   5         11
```

I think you can figure out how to make a `fmt` string that puts your numbers in the correct columns (join 26 spaces etc, or use left and right justification - the usual Python formatting issues).

`savetxt` also takes an opened file.  So you can open a file for writing, write one array, add some filler lines, and write another.  Also, `savetxt` doesn't do anything fancy.  It just iterates through the rows of the array, and writes each row to a line, e.g.

```
 for row in A:
     file.write(fmt % tuple(row))
```

So if you don't like the control that `savetxt` gives you, write the file directly.

Comment: In the lines [117] and [118] your output with your formatting gives you spacing which depend on the other integer. What I am looking for is a fmt option which lets me set spacing from left side regardless of other integers positions.

Comment: `fmt = ' '*26 + '%5d' + ' '*10 + '%10d'` or some such string construction.  Or (a 'bruteforce' formatting string :)) `fmt='_____________%6d__________%10d'`.